# Alternative for requests in while-loop

Tags: php, mysql

A while-loop returns lists containing translated words. In the overview, I want to show some of the list's words.

In my database, there is a list table with an id and another table with the words. A third table links lists and words.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result_lists):
    //Now I have to request the examples (five random words) 
endwhile;
```

This way of doing is, for certain, not the best way to do it. Is there a way to request the examples while I request the lists?

Comment: you can request five random words with while itself.

Comment: For sure, I am doing it this way. But in my opinion it is not a good solution to do a while while the while. :) Now there is a second loop in the while.

Comment: how you need your solution, say your expected result.